# why in this case copy constructor is matched?

Tags: c++11, initialization, list-initialization

I am curious about the C++11 list-initialization. I defined a class:

```
class base{
  base() { cout << "default ctor" << endl;}
  base(std::initiazer_list<base> il) { cout << "list initialization << endl;}
  base(const base &rhs) { cout << "copy ctor" << endl;}
}
```

In main function, I initialize two objects to test my class.

```
int main()
{
  base obj{}; // default ctor
  base obj2{obj}; // copy ctor
}
```

I learn from 《effective modern C++》 that calls using list-initialization syntax strongly prefer the overloads taking [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).
So, in my case, I think the second ctor will be called, however, the third is called.

Can you explain why?

Comment: First, this is not real code. Second, what's your compiler/version? The rules in this area underwent some recent changes.

Comment: I know my code does not have some practical meaning. I test my code in Visual Studio 2017RC.

Comment: I don't care about "practical meaning". This is self-evidently not the code you tested.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/e8DBgPbINm3vyfqV)

```
default ctor
copy ctor
list initialization
```

So, it's correct in the sense that first the copy constructor is called to copy `obj` to `std::initializer_list<base>` then the appropriate constructor overload (which is the one for initializer list) is called.

```
  base obj2{obj}; // copy ctor
```

As you can see this consists of two calls, not one. One to copy, one to list initialize. List initializer is the strongly preferred overload. The copy is to initialize the argument to that overload.

Edit: gcc and clang vary on this irrespective of version.

[GCC Head](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aqg2rvGKWZFSYqbP)
[Clang Head](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WiZ1PiyiGQkGDeYe)

I think what's happening is that `libstdc++` implementation of `std::initializer_list` creates temporary object, whereas clang picks up the copy constructor instead of initializer list overload.

Edit2:
I have checked this on my local system, clang with `-stdlib=libstdc++` does create temporary for `std::initializer_list` hence a call to copy constructor exists.

All compilers are correct that

Comment: Thanks for your answering. In my IDE(Visual Studio 2017RC), the output of my code is not same as yours. So , you mean it depends on the compiler?

Comment: @linyuwang Please check the edit. It does depend on the standard library implementation and compiler.

Comment: Clang is in an odd state: it implemented CWG1467 (which - among other things - says that this goes to the copy constructor), but not CWG2137 (which reverted this part of CWG1467 for non-aggregates).